# Very odd UIView position issue

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

I'm having a strange issue when it comes to adding content to a UIScrollView.

Below are the results for the same method getting called. The one on the left is the result of the call from viewDidLoad. The one one the right is called from a custom method which fires when the label is touched.

[image]

The code is pretty straight forward:

```
    CGRect scrollRect = CGRectMake(0, 64, 320, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height - 49);
    _containerView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:scrollRect];
    _containerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 300, 40)];
    myLabel.text = @"my label";
    myLabel.textColor = [super colorFromHexString:0x472C37];
    myLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    [myLabel sizeToFit];
    y_offset += myLabel.frame.size.height;
    [_containerView addSubview:myLabel];
    [self.view addSubView:_containerView];
```

I've checked the parent (self.view) and its coordinates are always 0,0. Really stumped by this...

Comment: Most likely a result of unspecified auto layout constraints.

Comment: Did work this code in `viewWillAppear:` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews`?

Comment: @DavidH Nope, not using auto layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `viewDidLoad` your subViews components are not totally initialized yet, so if you are using the frame of some of them you will get an undesired result. `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is probably what you are looking for. This is the method where all the subviews frames are completly initialized.

Try to call your code inside this method and you should get the same result as the one when clicking in the button.

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    [self setupView];
}
```